# The network path was not found for my database connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm trying to create a really simple social networking system. However, I get an error:

> The network path was not found

I know it's usually down to the connection string, which I have double checked, but can't find anything wrong with it.

**web.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connect" connectionString="Data Source=db555.db.1and1.com;Initial Catalog=db555;User ID=dbo555;Password=JJKSJUWJS$" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**The particular error console highlights the following however:**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connect"].ConnectionString;
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        EmailId = Session["EmailId"].ToString();
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select UserId from Registration where EmailId='" + EmailId + "'", con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            UserId = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["UserId"].ToString();
        }
        Session["UId"] = UserId;
        showPost();
    }
```

Comment: don't write passwords and username of your database. Also learn what is sql injection, don't share one sql connection.

Comment: many thanks @mybirthname, they are incorrect however... big time :-)

Comment: how does [tag:phpmyadmin] or [tag:social-networking] relate to the question?

Comment: try 'server=' instead of 'Data Source='. Also 'database=' instead of 'inital catalog='

Comment: from the machines that don't work, try `nslookup db555.db.1and1.com` from a command prompt.

Comment: Still, nothing. Most strange...

Comment: try pinging the server. In your command line, type ping db555.db.1and1.com and let us know the results.

Comment: @NepCoder ping request could not find host. The db555.db.1and.com is a SQL server attached to my website by the web-hosting company. However if you ping the server IP Address it says: `Ping statistics for 172.X.X.X:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 3ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 3ms`

Comment: Was "Still, nothing" in response to my comment about nslookup? That was not a fix, it would tell you if DNS was resolving. Similar to ping, but ping can be less reliable because it can be disabled.

Comment: @Crowcoder nslook up says: `UnKnown can't find db555.db.1and1.com: Non-existent domain` . Pardon me, for not saying anything useful back to yourself.

Comment: Right, that's your problem, its not a code issue. If that IP address works then use that in the connection string or create a Hosts entry on the computers or make a record in DNS if you can.